# people tracker - more than one person

Tags: ros, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
could it be possibile to use the people_tracking_filter of people package in order to track more than one person? How could this be implemented?
Thank you very much for your support

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199206/people-tracker---more-than-one-person/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Rahndall,
This package people_tracker says "This node wraps the OpenNI skeleton tracker so communicates directly to the kinect.". So it must be using something similar to the package openni_tracker, with which you can definitely track many users at the same time.
Then people_tracker tracks a specific torso it seems, there must be a way to select one among detected people, depends what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2014-12-10**:
Hi Cyril_J,
sorry for the misunderstanding: I was referring to the people_tracking_filter of people package. I edited in the question in the right way. Sorry for this